# Searching for way to scan barcodes for nutrition facts

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

Is there a way to access ALL nutrition facts of ALL food by scanning the barcodes on different product? Where would I find this?  I am developing a nutrition app.  I want to be able to just scan the item and the nutrition facts of each item are added to what is about to be eaten.

Answer (score -1):

The Nutritionix API provides access to nutrition data from over 600K barcodes from the US, Canada and the UK:

https://www.nutritionix.com/business/api

Full disclosure: I work for Nutritionix.